# Symfony framework voting system

Tags: symfony1, voting

Can someone give me some links to a maybe guide or to a symfony plugin, for voting system.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a star rating system plugin for Symfony.  I am not sure if you are looking for a polling system or a voting system.

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/mpStarRatingPlugin

I have not tested this.

I am not aware of any polling plugins for the latest version of symfony.

Answer (score 0):

What would be useful to know is what type of voting you need, as there may be good solutions that you can incorporate into your Symfony project easily, such as this [Jquery star rating](http://colorpowered.com/colorrating/), which will take care of making the frontend implementation pretty.

Comment: Some simple rating,just 2 buttons, up and down.

Comment: I'd probably build something this simple from scratch: a TINYINT field in some table for the backend and Jquery Ajax for up/down frontend functionality like here on StackOverflow.